# Grep to match the pattern exactly

Tags: grep

I am trying to grep the specific pattern `/home/mytest/data` from each line of `1.txt` file and when the match is found then copy the complete line to `2.txt` file. But result set in `2.txt` file is not the expected result.

**Code**

```
i=/home/mytest/data
IFS=',' read -ra ADDR <<< "$File_Name"
Input=1.txt
for i in "${ADDR[@]}";
do
  j=0
  while IFS= read -r line;
  do
    j=$((j+1))
    Exists=$(echo $line | grep -w "$i" )
    if [[ ! -z "$Exists" ]]; then
      cp=$(echo $line >> 2.txt)
    fi
  done <"$Input"
```

**Expected Result - 2.txt**

```
# file: /home/mytest/data # owner: own # group: group-sm user::r-x group::rwx mask::rwx other::--- default:user::rwx default:group::r-x default:group:smr:rwx default:group:agm:r-x default:mask::rwx default:other::---
```

**Actual Result - 2.txt**

```
# file: /home/mytest/data # owner: own # group: group-sm user::r-x group::rwx mask::rwx other::--- default:user::rwx default:group::r-x default:group:smr:rwx default:group:agm:r-x default:mask::rwx default:other::---
# file: /home/mytest/datasr123 # owner: own # group: group-sm user::r-x group::rwx mask::rwx other::---
```

---

Grep version: GNU grep 2.20

Comment: What Unix are you using?  And more importantly, what `grep` are you using?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the string _does_ occur on both lines.  Can we assume that the string that you are trying to match is always an absolute path?

Comment: what unix ?? what grep ?? not getting you

Comment: Are you running Linux? What distribution of Linux in that case? What is the output of `grep --version`?

Comment: yes. GNU grep 2.20

Comment: ya it would be absolute path always

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103989/discussion-between-user78873-and-kusalananda).

Comment: After a little formatting of you code it is clear that it will not run.

Comment: This is the 4th question you've asked without accepting any answers. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for what to do when someone answers your question as continuing to ask questions without accepting any answers discourages people from trying to help you.

Comment: @EdMorton : Sure, I am very much happy to accept the answers if it solves the posted query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that with the (non-standard) option `-w`, `grep` will require a word boundary before and after the pattern.  A "word boundary" is a transition between a word and a non-word.  A "word" is a string that contains word characters, like `a`, `b`, etc., while a non-word is a string that contains characters like space, `/`, `?`, etc.

Since `/` is not a "word character", there can be no word boundary before it (unless it is immediately *preceded* by a word character). Some versions of `grep` would therefore not be able to match the string in your data, ever.  Other versions *would* be able to perform the match.

Since you seem to want to match the path on a line where it is immediately preceded `# file:` , and since we know that the path is followed by  `# owner:` on the same line, we can use these strings as delimiters for the given path:

```
querypath=/home/mytest/data

grep -F "# file: $querypath # owner:" 1.txt >2.txt
```

Comment: no its not working out

Comment: ya tried it and then only i posted the above comment

Comment: @user78873 Is your script file a DOS text file? Did you write it on a Windows machine?  In that case, convert it to a Unix text file with `dos2unix`.

Comment: @Kusalananda : no its unix bash script only.

Comment: @user78873  Well, what can I say. If I copy and paste your text and run the commands, it works on OpenBSD (with both native and GNU `grep`), and it also works on CentOS and on Ubuntu.